# C# Read dynamically added properties form the settings file

Tags: c#

I am using this code to dynamically add a property to the Properties.settings file.
This is working well until I restart the program.
When I restart the program the properties I've added will not load until I add them again.
The property will have the same value then as the last time it was saved.

It is useless to use this if I can't access the values between runtime's.
The only solution I can think of is saving all the name's of the property's somwhere but then I have the same problem.
Is ther a way to bypass this ?
Thanks in advance!

```
string propName = "randomName";
System.Configuration.SettingsProperty property = new System.Configuration.SettingsProperty(propName);
property.DefaultValue = "Default";
property.IsReadOnly = false;
property.PropertyType = typeof(string);
property.Provider = Properties.Settings.Default.Providers["LocalFileSettingsProvider"];
property.Attributes.Add(typeof(System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute), new System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute());
Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Add(property);
Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Save();
Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Reload();
```

(The answer of [Create new settings on runtime and read after restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018606/create-new-settings-on-runtime-and-read-after-restart) doesn't work)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create new settings on runtime and read after restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018606/create-new-settings-on-runtime-and-read-after-restart)

Comment: what is `Properties` ?

Comment: Properties as in Properties.Settings ?
It is the location where the settings are stored (I think)