# How to save Settings at runtime in C# Winforms App

Tags: c#, appsettings

I am developing a fairly basic winforms app in .Net 6 that has some settings that I need to save locally at runtime.

THis piece of Code

```
Properties.Settings.Default["comPort"] = cboComPorts.Text;
```

I get the error:

> System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyNotFoundException
> HResult=0x80131500
> Message=The settings property 'comPort' was not found.
> Source=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

Ideally - I would like to save the settings in a file at runtime

- creating a new setting if it doesn't exist
- or overwrite the setting if it does exist.

I have tried creating a "Settings.settings" file as well - but I can't quite get my head around why it won't write the setting.

Comment: i have not used .net6. But when i use properties i have to go to project settings and actually create the properties i want to be able to read/write to.

Comment: What about the scope of the settings. Are they user based scope?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c#: Create new settings at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175726/c-create-new-settings-at-run-time)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create new settings on runtime and read after restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018606/create-new-settings-on-runtime-and-read-after-restart)

Comment: [ConfigurationManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're properly adding the settings file. Add a folder to your project named `Properties`. For Visual Studio right click on the folder and select *Add -> New Item -> Settings File*. You should have `Settings.Designer.cs` and `Settings.settings` in your properties file. It should look like this when you open it;

[image]

Fetch, set and update the setting like so;

```
int savedPort = Properties.Settings.Default.comPort;
Properties.Settings.Default.comPort = 1;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```